# Twitter bootstrap affixed sidebar collapses when I scroll down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a sidebar like the ones in Twitter bootstrap docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html

I've got the affix working and all but whenever you scroll past the data-offset the bar collapses because it has no .

HTML

```
<div class="span3">
          <ul data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="255" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked docs-sidebar" id="navbar">
            <li><a href="#grid">Grid system <i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fluidGridSystem">Fluid grid system <i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#layouts">Layouts <i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#responsive">Responsive design <i class="icon-chevron-right pull-right"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <p></p>
       </div>
```

LESS

```
    // For Affix plugin
.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: (@navbarHeight * 1.8) + @navbarPadding + 25px;
}

.docs-sidebar {
    width: (@gridColumnWidth * 4);
}
```

This makes the sidebar a fixed span4 width but doesn't make it responsive. How do I make sure it is responsive?

Comment: I had this same problem. I resorted to using media queries to replace the affix sidebar with a responsive navbar. But if you examine the bootstrap page you can see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

I too am trying to figure out the best way to do this. Here's what I have done. Maybe not the best solution but it's working.

I have a two column layout where I want the left to .affix. I pulled the column to fix out of the row and put it in its own row above the original. I moved the remaining column back in place by adding .offset3. I put .affix on the column div instead of the ul. Then I wrapped the fixed column in a div with CSS of position:absolute; (that's inside the .row div and outside the .col3 div) That puts two .row divs to overlap where one is fixed and the other scrolling.